# How exactly does Monitor.Wait(obj, timeout) work?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timeout, locking

In the .NET world, there is a method called `Monitor.Wait(object obj, TimeSpan timeout)`. My question pertains to how the `TimeSpan timeout` argument works in particular. The question is, can we rely on the `Wait` method to time-out after `timeout` *milliseconds* has actually passed? Or, will it take longer than `timeout` milliseconds?

In short, how accurate is the lock-released time, with respect to the specified value of `timeout`?

Additionally, I would like to disregard the scenario where other threads are trying to obtain the lock, and for the sake of this question let's just assume that there is one thread in the wait-state needing to be pulsed.

Comment: It will not take less.  Beyond the clock tick interrupt granularity (15.6 msec or less) there is no guarantee that the thread resumes immediately.  It has to compete with all the other threads that run on the machine and is subject to page faults and garbage collection delays like any code.  Hundreds of milliseconds is possible.

Comment: @HansPassant Is it different than a `Thread.Sleep` (which could be order of magnitude slower)? Or more accurate? I don't expect you to have all the answers, but am just trying to get a rough idea.

Comment: It is exactly the same as Thread.Sleep().  It is *never* an order of magnitude, if you sleep/timeout for 1 second then it won't turn into 10 seconds.  The latency only depends on what else is happening on the machine.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok helfpul. So "disregard the scenario where other threads are trying to obtain the lock" was a pointless thing to add to my question, because that's really what influences the time-out?

Comment: That's roughly correct.  It does not affect the timeout, it affects how long it takes for your code to start running again.  You can't tell the difference.

Comment: @HansPassant Great, thanks.